# Combine TapGestureRecognizer and PanGestureRecognizer in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following structure.

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
Grid grid = new Grid();
ContentView contentView = new ContentView();
contentView.GestureRecognizers.Add(CreateSwipeEffect());
grid.Children.Add(contentView, 0, 0);
frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(CreateFrameTapEffect());
frame.Content = grid;
```

Frame has available two effects: first we can swipe(PanGesture) and second we can tap(TapGesture). On iOS platform this solution perfectly works. However on Android platform only swipe effect is firing. How can I solve this to have both effects available for Android platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dispatching Tap Event to Frame(parent) and Swip Event to ContentView(childview).
According to [Input events overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events):

> Remember that hardware key events are always delivered to the View
>   currently in focus. They are dispatched starting from the top of the
>   View hierarchy, and then down, until they reach the appropriate
>   destination.

So based on your codes when you are tapping on the Frame, android system thought you want to fire the tap event on ContentView(which doesn't exist) because current focus is the contentview not the frame. So if you have specific needs to do that, you need to try other ways to implement it. If not, please register the tap event on ContentView.

Answer (score 1):

I use your code in iOS and Android, yes, it works fine on iOS, and have issue on Android.

But if you add tapGenture and panGesture after you add label or frame control, it can works fine. Maybe some mechanisms of Android are a little different from iOS. Please take a look the following code, I test it on Android and iOS, it all works fine.

```
 public Page17()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += PanGesture_PanUpdated;
        var tapGenture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGenture.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapGenture.Tapped += TapGenture_Tapped;

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Label label= new Label();
        label.Text = "this is test!";
        label.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;



        grid.Children.Add(label,0,0);

        frame.Content = grid;
        stacklayout1.Children.Add(frame);

        frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGenture);

        label.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    private void TapGenture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the tapgesture fire!");
    }

    private void PanGesture_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the pangesture fire");
    }
```

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT check exactly with content view solution.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT. I suggest to extend label in frame to fill maximum. Then only pan gesture effect works, so it is not good solution.

Comment: @maciejka, I can reproduce your issue when I extend label in frame, please feedback this issue in github for Xamarin.Forms, I also feedback this issue for Microsoft team, thanks.

Comment: in your example red label does not fill completely vertically and horizontally grid. When you fill completely, then there is no white space and then tap effect is not working, only pan gesture effect is working.